# How to update a specific column without disturbance in other columns in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
("update Medicine set  Name = ' " + textbox1.Text + " ', Company = ' " + textbox2.Text + " ', Type = ' " + textbox3.Text + " ', Quantity = ' " + textbox4.Text + " ' where P_id =' " + textbox5.Text + " '  ");
```

It does not working because whenever I update any column it makes other columns NULL.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: If you don't want to set other columns, don't set the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious solution is to construct the `update` with lists of columns.

An alternative is to use `coalesce()`:

```
update Medicine
    set Name = coalesce(' " + textbox1.Text + " ', Name),
        Company = coalesce(' " + textbox2.Text + " ', Company),
        Type = coalesce(' " + textbox3.Text + " ', Type,
        Quantity = coalesce(' " + textbox4.Text + " ', Quantity)
 where P_id =' " + textbox5.Text + " '
```

Actually, you should be using parameters rather than directly putting values in the query string.  Putting parameters in directly makes the system vulnerable to SQL injection.

That said, I'm not sure how you are getting `NULL` values.  You might really want:

```
update Medicine
    set Name =(case when ' " + textbox1.Text + " ' = '' then '" + textbox1.Text + "' else Name end),
        . . .
```